# Which is better for best practice about passing getServerSideProps type to Next.Js page props

Tags: typescript, next.js

I found two solutions that work correctly but i cant sure which is more consistent approach.

```
interface ICatalogHome {
    response: Result<CatalogHomePageResponse>;
}
```

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<ICatalogHome> = async (context) => {
    const appSlug = context.params?.appSlug;
    const { locale } = context;
    const response = await getCatalogHomePageData(appSlug as string, locale!);

    const notFound = !response;

    return {
        props: {
            response,
            ...(await serverSideTranslations(context.locale!, ['common', 'login']))
        }, // will be passed to the page component as props
        notFound
    };
};
```

First Approach:

```
const CatalogHome: NextPage<InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>> = ({ response }) => {...}
```

Second Approach:

```
const CatalogHome = ({ response }: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>) => {...}
```

Comment: I came across usages like in 2nd approach in different codes. I'm wondering which is the better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine, especially if you only want your props typed.

I prefer the **first approach** as it also types other props injected by `next`, such as `req`, `res`, or `pathname`. It will also add a return type, which is not happening in the second approach.